# how to add elements between sections in Fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

i was trying to add some parallax effect backgrounds between sections in the fullpage.js plugin

code goes something like this

```html
<div class="fallpage">
  <div class="section">content</div>
  <div class="parallex-background"></div>
  <div class="section">content</div>
  <div class="parallex-background"></div>
  <div class="section">content</div>
</div>
```

everything works fine , and fullpage.js ignores those parallax sections , except for the scrolling part... mouse doesn't work anymore or the keyboard controls , side-dots and menu works fine

if i could just make the plugin ignore these parallax backgrounds between sections with the mouse wheel scrolling and the keyboard controls working , that would be great :)

and sorry for any typos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can't do that**. Fullpagejs will only expect sections between sections.

What you can do instead is playing with fullpage.js options. Use them as sections, use the `fp-auto-height` class for them so they won't be full screen, and use some callback to force fullpage.js to jump them when you are about to arrive to them:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
        var destinationToIgnore = $('.section').eq(nextIndex -1).hasClass('ignore');

        if(destinationToIgnore){
            var destination = (direction === 'down') ? nextIndex + 1 : nextIndex - 1
            $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(destination);
        }
    }
});
```

I've coded this script in a way that you just need to use the class `ignore` in your section to force fullpage.js to ignore it, for example:

```
<div class="section fp-auto-height ignore">
    <div class="parallax">
        PARALLAX
    </div>
</div>
```

[Reproduction online](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/1067/)

Now you can give me an up-vote, a hug, a lollipop, or even a donation! :)

Comment: Don't forgot to accept the answer and upvote it ! :) That's useful for other people as well!

Comment: turns out all i actually needed is the fp-auto-height class , and sir you are a genius , thanks!

since i'm using dots , it adds a dot for every new section even the parallaxes ones , i had to deal with it using :nth-child(even){display:none;}

and adding parallax between every two anchors , so it goes to the right section , and adding parallax between every two nav tooltips so it shows the right section name..

my high appreciations friend :)